# Neo4j queries to get newly added/modifed list of nodes/relationships with in the given time period

Tags: neo4j

Ex:
1) At 10 AM I queried the graph db I got 10 nodes and 12 relationships.
After 15 min, i.e at 10.15 AM I queried graph db again and I got 12 nodes and 14 relationships.
My question is to query the grahp db b/w 10 AM to 10.15 AM and I should get 2 nodes and 2 relationships if it is newly added. How is this possible?

2) Instead of adding new node/relationships if there is a modification in the existing node and relationships(like property added/modified) between the time period I should get to know that these are the nodes and relationships which are modified.
Please anybody help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't an easy question to answer in its current form. Can you give some examples of the kind of data you are dealing with? There is no native support in Neo4j for what you are talking about, so you will have to include it in the graph model. Modelling discussions are difficult in the abstract, so a concrete example will help enormously.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to track changes explicitly in the graph, using either some graph structure like http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/cypher-cookbook-path-tree.html or http://gist.neo4j.org/?github-kbastani/gists//meta/TimeScaleEventMetaModel.adoc or https://github.com/SocioPatterns/neo4j-dynagraph/wiki/Representing-time-dependent-graphs-in-Neo4j, or use some form of property on nodes that you index on for tracking changes.